# Chaining multiple asynchronous methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a javascript library to abstract ajax requests to my HTTP API.
Each of my javascript functions is a wrapper for jquery's ajax call, which makes a callback to the user on completion.

Eg.

```
mylib.doThing( "foo", { success:function(){alert("done");});
```

In the case where I want to execute mylib.doFoo twice in series, I have something like:

```
mylib.doThing( "foo", { success:function(){ mylib.doThing( "bar", { success:function(){alert("done");}); });
```

For anything more that two steps, this gets messy very quickly.

Is it possible to provide a cleaner syntax, perhaps more like the following? And how would I need to implement `mylib.doThing()`?

```
mylib.doThing("foo").mylib.doThing("bar").alert("done");
```

Comment: In your wrapper function itself, you should use `.done()` as opposed to `success`, as `success` is set to be depricated in the next release of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doThingFluent(a, b) {
  return {
    _name : a,
    _chainedCall : b,
    doMoreThingFluent : function(a1) {
      return doThing(a1, this);
    },
    done : function(callback) {
      var chained = this._chainedCall;
      var name = this._name;
      while (chained) {
        callback = function(n, c) {
          return function() {
            mylib.doThing(n, { success : c });
          };
        } (name, callback);
        name = chained._name;
        chained = chained._chainedCall;
      }

      mylib.doThing(name, {success: callback});
    }
 };

 doThingFluent("foo").doMoreThingFluent("bar").done(function(){alert("done");})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to chain unspecified number of successful requests with doing something in the end, listing all things to do as a natural list instead of chain of methods would be even cleaner:

```
mylib.doThing("foo", "bar", /* all done callback -> */ function() { alert("done") })
```

`doThing` would have inside a factory that would create either nested callbacks or - even better - iterative manager that'd run all requests in sequence and then call final callback.

Comment: How can I write the internal factory without hardcoding for a fixed number of arguments? (ie. just copying my original code)

Comment: @JobyTaffey Walk through the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) array-like object.