# How to use jQuery when function with more postJSON queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have a problem at work: I have a section of installations which are dependent on servers. I want to do this: When a user deletes a server, it loops through installations collection and deletes all dependent installations. For that I use jQuery 'when' function, which is said to wait for a response from the server and then move on to 'then' function. It works flawlessly when there is only one dependent installation. A problem occurs when there are more installations, however, because it moves to the 'then' function immediately after receiving a JSON response.

The question is: How do I make 'when' function wait for all server responses? Eg. I send out three delete requests through $.postJSON and want to move on *after* I get all three responses. If it's not possible with 'when', what should I use to make it happen? If it helps, I maintain all my entities collections with KnockoutJS. Thanks!

EDIT:
I have it like this:

```
$.when(DeleteDependentInstallations())
.then (function() {
   ...
});
```

DeleteDependentInstallations looks like (pseudocode):

```
Search the installations collection;
If installation.ID equals server.InstallationID
{
  Add to dependent installations collection;
}
Repeat until the whole collection is searched;

for (i = 0; i < dependentInstallations.length; i++)
{
  DeleteInstallation(dependentInstallations[i]);
}
```

DeleteInstallations is a simple function using $.postJSON function.

The problem is the .then function executes immediately after the first JSON response.

Comment: Code. Example. Whathaveyoutried.

Comment: `$.when()` waits for either *all resolves* **or** *the first reject*. This questions seems to be a duplicate. I've made a modified version of `$.when()` and there's a couple of other answers over at **[jQuery.when - Callback for when ALL Deferreds are no long 'unresolved' (either resolved or rejected)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824615/jquery-when-callback-for-when-all-deferreds-are-no-long-unresolved-either-r)**

Comment: I added a pseudocode of how I do it. I think this case is a bit different that the one at the link you posted, hippietrail.

Comment: why did you include knockoutjs on this?  Is Knockout something your'e using elsewhere?  Or is Knockout something you thought would be a good fix?

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432358/chaining-multiple-asynchronous-methods-in-javascript/11432543#11432543

Comment: This is only a small part of the whole website, which uses Knockout as the presentation layer.

Comment: Does `DeleteDependantInstallations()` return an array of jquery Promises? If you made that return an array of the return values of your ajax calls, when() *should* wait for each of them to complete.

Comment: @blesh: This is the first time I hear of jQuery promises, how would I do that?

Comment: I added an answer that explains what I mean (I hope).  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have DeleteDependentInstallations return an array of JQuery *deferreds*. [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) allows you to pass multiple arguments to it in order to let it know it has to wait for each one.

I don't know the whole context of what you're doing, but I think something like this might work:

```
function DeleteDependentInstallations() {
     var installations = getDependantInstallations();
     var promises = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < installations.length; i++) {
         var installation = installations[i];
         promises.push(DeleteInstallation(installation));
     }
     return promises;
}

function DeleteInstallation(installation) {
      //do whatever here, but return the result of $.ajaxPost
      return $.post('/foo', installation);
}
```

Now when you use that method, it should wait for all returned promises to complete.

```
$.when.apply(null, DeleteDependentInstallations()).then(function() { alert('wee!'); });
```

The .apply() is so we can pass an array as an arguments collection.

EDIT: I was confusing "deferreds" and promises in my head. [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) are what the $.ajax calls return, and a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) is what the $.when() function returns.

EDIT2: You might also want to look at the [.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) method, if the behavior of .then() doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it tommorow when I get to work and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Connected to my company's VPN and tried it. Works like a charm, million thanks, blesh!

Comment: No sweat. Deferreds and Promises are a powerful but little known feature of JQuery. You can even roll your own deferreds for any custom async code you might do.

Comment: Here's an example of a custom deferred implementation: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/